# UITableView scroll to section that is closest to todays date

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `tableview` with a calendar it's appointments in it. Each day is a separate `section`. 
You can see what I mean over here

[image]

Now I want that the `tableview` scrolls to the `section` of today or if there is no `section` for today to the closest one.

I know that I should use the following piece of code:

```
 [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

Now I have an `NSMutableDictionary` that contains my sorted Appointments/day. You can see the function below:

```
-(NSDictionary *)sortKalendar:(NSMutableArray *)appointments{
    NSMutableDictionary *buffer = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

    for (int i = 0; i < appointments.count; i++) {
        Appointment *object = [appointments objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *date = [formatter stringFromDate:object.app_start];
        if(!(date == NULL) ){
            NSLog(@"date is %@",date);
            if ([buffer objectForKey:date]) {
                [(NSMutableArray *)[buffer objectForKey:date] addObject:object];
            } else {
                NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:object, nil];
                [buffer setObject:mutableArray forKey:date];
            }
        }


    }
    NSDictionary *result = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:buffer];

    return result;
}
```

My question is now, how can I find the correct `NSIndexpath` ?

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT**

At the moment I'm using the following. But something is still not right.

```
NSArray *keys = [dictAppointments allKeys];

NSLog(@"KEYS ARE %@",keys)  ;
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

NSArray *sortedArray = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:obj1];
    NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:obj2];

    NSNumber *interval1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[date1 timeIntervalSinceNow]];
    NSNumber *interval2 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[date2 timeIntervalSinceNow]];
    return (NSComparisonResult)[interval1 compare:interval2];
}];
NSLog(@"Sorted Array %@",sortedArray);
NSString *closestDateString = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Closest date string is %@",closestDateString);
int section = [keys indexOfObject:closestDateString];
NSIndexPath *scrollIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

This gives me the following logs:

```
2014-01-07 13:28:42.420 Adsolut[9579:60b] KEYS ARE (
    "03-12-2013",
    "20-12-2013",
    "17-12-2013",
    "05-01-2014",
    "21-12-2013",
    "31-12-2013",
    "04-01-2014",
    "06-01-2014",
    "16-01-2014",
    "29-12-2013",
    "03-01-2014",
    "11-01-2014",
    "18-12-2013",
    "31-01-2014"
)
2014-01-07 13:28:42.437 Adsolut[9579:60b] Sorted Array (
    "03-12-2013",
    "17-12-2013",
    "18-12-2013",
    "20-12-2013",
    "21-12-2013",
    "29-12-2013",
    "31-12-2013",
    "03-01-2014",
    "04-01-2014",
    "05-01-2014",
    "06-01-2014",
    "11-01-2014",
    "16-01-2014",
    "31-01-2014"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the array using time interval between appointment date and current date,

```
NSArray *keys = [yourDictionary allKeys];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

NSArray *sortedArray = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:obj1];
    NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:obj2];

    NSNumber *interval1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:abs([date1 timeIntervalSinceNow])];
    NSNumber *interval2 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:abs([date2 timeIntervalSinceNow])];
    return (NSComparisonResult)[interval1 compare:interval2];
}];
```

And the closest date by,

```
NSString *closestDateString = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

And from that,

```
int section = [keys indexOfObject:closestDateString];
NSIndexPath *scrollIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section];
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer. But at the moment I still getting the first date as closestDateString back.

Comment: @StefGeelen array is not sorted? Log `keys` and `sortedArray`. these are same?

Comment: the array is sorted. But now the way I want it. I want the date closest to todays date.

Comment: @StefGeelen Try the `abs` value of timeInterval. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a sorted date array, don't you? Let's say it as `dateArray`.

Get today date object: `NSDate * today = [NSDate date];`

Search for dateArray to the nearest date, get the index of nearest date.

```
NSDate * today = [NSDate date] ;
__block NSUInteger section = NSNotFound ;
__block NSTimeInterval timeInterval = NSTimeIntervalSince1970 ;
[dateArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDate * date = obj ;
    NSTimeInterval ti = [today timeIntervalSinceDate:date] ;
    if (ti < 0)
        ti = -ti ;
    if (ti <= timeInterval) {
        section = idx ;
        timeInterval = ti ;
    } else {
        *stop = YES ;
    }
}] ;
```

You know the section index now, let's say it as `sectionIndex`, the first row index in the section is 0.

So the NSIndexPath is `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:sectionIndex]`

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of dates (from your dictionary or one you already have). Sort it. Loop over it (`indexOfObjectPassingTest:`) to find the date `>=` today (or use a predicate to filter and then take the first item from the result and get the index).